# Offsetof used in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I was going through how offset of a particular variable is found in a given structure.

I tried the following program .

```
struct info{
char a;
int b;
char c;
int d;
};

struct info myinfo;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
struct info *ptr = &myinfo;
unsigned int offset;

offset = (unsigned int) &((struct info *) 0)->d;
printf("Offset = %d\n",offset);

return 0;
}
```

I just wanted to know how the line `offset = (unsigned int) &((struct info *) 0)->d` works.
I am confused because of dereferencing of 0.

Comment: In case this isn't obvious: use `offsetof` instead. This might be how it's implemented, but if so then it's the compiler's problem to know that it'll work, instead of yours.

Comment: @SteveJessop - While I agree, for some reason the Linux kernel developers don't.

Comment: @Chris: well, if there's a sensible reason then good luck to them, but linux kernel developers have made serious mistakes in the past where they have incorrectly guessed the behavior of of GCC in UB situations. Best not to get involved in anything hairy without knowing the reasons :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not *really* dereference `0`, although it looks like it. It really takes the address of some member if it was dereferenced at address `0`, hypothetically.

This is a kind of dirty hack (plus, some nasty macro stuff), but it gets you what you're interested in (the offset of the member in the struct).

A more "correct" way of doing the same thing would be to generate a valid object, take its address, and take the address of the member, then subtract these. Doing the same with a null pointer is not all pretty, but works without creating an object and subtracting anything.

Comment: Just was about to post the same. Maybe in other words: If there would be this struct starting at memory location 0, where would be the address of member `d`? BTW: I don't think it's dirty ;-)

Comment: The C99 standard doesn't require `&((type *)0)->member` to optimize out the dereference. And even if it did, it would optimize to `(char *)0 + offsetof(type, member)`, which does pointer arithmetic on a `NULL` pointer, which is still undefined behavior. It works because Linux is only compiled with GCC, and GCC lets it work.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: "does pointer arithmetic on a NULL pointer, which is still undefined behavior" -- That is the exact reason why I said "dirty". But luckily, it works fine on every major compiler anyway (it ought to work too, if the compiler manufacturer implements it that way).

Comment: So that means I can give anything other than 0 then .For example 'offset = (unsigned int) &((struct info *) 1000)->d' ??

Comment: @Damon - Fair enough. Also possible is to use `1024`, which ought to be aligned properly for any object, and ought to at least be addressable. Technically the dereference could be UB, but it will work in the event that your compiler warns about performing pointer arithmetic on `NULL`. (Someone told me on here a while ago that they had to change `offsetof` in their system headers from `0` to `1024` to avoid warnings from a newer compiler once.)

Comment: @LeoMessi - Not anything. It'd have to be aligned properly for an object of the given type.

Comment: @ChrisLutz : But if you use 1024 my guess is that the offset will come to 1036 right ??

Comment: @LeoMessi - Well, depends on your system, but assuming `sizeof(int) == 4` and that `int`s are aligned on word boundaries, yes. (You can, of course, get the correct offset by subtracting the initial value at the end, if that's your concern).

Comment: @ChrisLutz : Yup perfect ..Got it ...So thats why in Linux to avoid all this headache they probably have used `0` ...Thanks for your Info..:)

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually dereferencing 0. You're adding zero and the offset of the member, since you're taking the address of the expression. That is, if **off** is the offset of the member, you're doing

```
0 + off
```

not

```
*(0 + off)
```

so you never actually do a memory access.

Comment: Performing pointer arithmetic on a `NULL` pointer is undefined behavior. It may work, and it works for Linux because they only use GCC, but it doesn't have to. More reliable would be to use `1024`, which should be aligned to whatever word-boundary your system uses, and should be addressable (though probably not dereferenceable, but you don't need it to be).

Comment: @Chris Lutz: **No - this is not performing illegal pointer arithmetic on a NULL pointer**. NULL++ would be, because the target's size of NULL is not defined (because it could be `(int *0)`, `(char *)0`, `(void *)0` or something else depending on the compiler used). But in *this* example it's totally clear to the compiler what the target type is and 0 is only the starting location of the struct being pointed to. Or said the other way around: If 0 would not be an allowed value for pointer, lists of offsets would break all over the place.

Comment: @ktf - The standard explicitly states that pointer arithmetic on a null pointer value, regardless of type, is undefined behavior. This is probably because a null pointer doesn't need to be 0, and so the resultant value might not necessarily be what you expect. You're allowed to do pointer arithmetic with the integer 0: `int arr[4] = {0}; &arr[0]` but not with a null pointer: `int *ptr = 0; &ptr[4];`

Comment: @Chris Lutz: pls. state where in the standard this would be. From what I see only expressions with the *null pointer constant* are not allowed (that would be `NULL` or `(void *)0`), but surely I may use *null pointer values* like `(int *)0` or `(struct foo *)0`

Comment: @ktf - The section on the addition and subtraction operators (didn't remember the number, I'm lazy and on my phone) only defines pointer arithmetic for objects within the same array (treating non-array objects as an array of 1), so since a null pointer doesn't point to an object there's no valid "array" to perform arithmetic on. And you ignored my point that a null pointer isn't required to be all-bits-zero at the machine level, meaning that even `(char *)0 + 1` won't necessarily give you the pointer `0x1`, meaning that the result has to be undefined.